# MySQL - looping through tables, updating column 'Day' where values match in another column 'Week'

Tags: mysql, loops, while-loop

I am looping through a bunch of tables which include the Columns Date, Week and Day. Several rows have the same Week Number for multiple Dates e.g. the dates 2015-12-24, 2015-12-23, 2015-12-22, 2015-12-21 are all 'Week' 52.

I want to add the day of week e.g. 1 through to 5 to the 'Day' Column for 'Week' e.g. 52. Below is my code so far, I do not know what to do while inside each table to achieve the above result.

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $db";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$res) {
  echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
  echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
  exit;
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {

  //Update Day in the Tables
  $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM $row[0]"; 
  $res1 = mysql_query($sql1);

  while(($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($res1))!=null)
  {
    //What do I put here?!
  }

}
```

Comment: Columns 'WEEK' and 'DAY' are redundant. You can get this data directly from DATE column, you don't need a separate columns for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `update` statement instead of a loop

```
UPDATE
    "your_table"
SET
    "your_table"."Day"=weekday("your_table"."Date")
WHERE
    "your_table"."Week"=52
```